# Submit wordpress form if selected value changes without button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, submit, onchange

I'm trying to submit a form without a submit button.
This form takes values from custom fields in wordpress, displaying results in another page. I've been trying with the usual javascript function onchange and nothing happens, I've tried with functions as well...does anyone know what's wrong with this or if is there a better way to solve it? Can it be something related to Wordpress, or the post method? This is the code for the form:

```
<form method="get" name="form" action="/busqueda/" >
        <div class="search">

            <select class="styled" name="author"  onChange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="-1" selected>Authors</option>    
            <?php
            $metakey = 'author';
            $autores = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
            if ($authors) {
            foreach ($authors as $author) {
            echo "<option VALUE=\"" . $author . "\">" . $author . "</option>";
                                    }
                            }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div><!-- #search1 -->

</form>
```

BTW, the form works fine when displaying results with  a standard submit button.
Any hint of what can be wrong is welcome. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why compare values? I just want it to go to the results search page, but without the button :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<form method="get" name="form" action="/busqueda/" >
        <div class="search">

            <select class="styled" name="author" onChange="document.forms['form'].submit();">

            <?php
            $metakey = 'author';
            $autores = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
            if ($authors) {
            foreach ($authors as $author) {
            echo "<option VALUE=\"" . $author . "\">" . $author . "</option>";
                                    }
                            }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div><!-- #search1 -->

</form>
```

#### Updated with jQuery submit

The updated form:

```
<form id="authorForm" method="get" name="form" action="/busqueda/" >
        <div class="search">

            <select id="author" class="styled" name="author">
                <option value="default">Choose an author...</option>
                <?php
                $metakey = 'author';
                $autores = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s ORDER BY meta_value ASC", $metakey) );
                if ($authors){
                    foreach ($authors as $author) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $author . '">' . $author . '</option>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div><!-- #search1 -->

</form>
```

jQuery script change event handling and form submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#author').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() !== 'default'){
            $('#authorForm').submit();
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

You can test the [jQuery from submit on drop box change event](http://jsfiddle.net/b8SjT/)

Comment: Thanks, @Shef. I already tried that as well and still not working. I believe the javascript is fine. Can it be that something is interfering with this? I have another form in the same page, but no it doesnt have any button named "submit" which I believe is a common error. What else could it be that doesn't make this work in any browser? :( Or is there another way I could try? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... please show us an online page where we can take a look at it, and start debugging from there. Does the form submit at all when you change the author or not? I.e. does it take you to `site.com/busqueda/?author=abcd` when you change the author?

Comment: @Shef, I can't give you an online page as this is part of an ongoing job and I can't display it :( The form does work with a submit button, taking you to site.com/busqueda. It's a wordpress site, so I had to make a new page and link a custom template page named "busqueda", which deals with results and shows them (I can post that if thats helpful). It looks like if the javascript is not seen, as Im trying onChange="alert('alert') and nothing happens on changing authors..

Comment: Seems like [WordPress has an issue with JavaScript](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-java-script-to-page)

Comment: Ouch. Shall I try with jquery? I have this library installed and it works fine with some other elements in the page.

Comment: Yeah, you can try with jQuery. I will update the answer with a jQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks again, @Shef. I had already tried with jQuery (your code is fine!!)and neither work. Now I've also tried with another form (wordpress native): <form name="catform" action="index.php" method="get">
<select name="cat" onchange="submit(this.form)">
<option value='<?php dropdown_cats(); ?>
</option>
</select>
</form> ////// This onchange is working fine. This is something related to either the option value or the action in the form. Which is kind of annoying if the submit button does work. I'm puzzled! And I understand if you want to give up on this :)

Comment: What do you mean this `onchange` works? Does it take you to `site.com/busqueda/?author=abc` when you change the option, or not?

Comment: It doesn't submit, because your form doesn't have an ID. Change your from to this `<form method="get" action="/busqueda-az/" name="authorForm" id="authorForm">`. I just tested on your site, it works fine if you add the id. :)

Comment: Oh my!!! so it's been a matter of ids all the time? xDD Thanks so much @Shef, I've learned a lot :D

Comment: Hmm... maybe, or maybe you were not listening correctly to the `onchange` event. That doesn't matter now, what matters is that it's solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are retrieving the value after the post correctly through $_GET because when i ran the code in my browser, the value is passing on in the URL quite nicely. Check your retrieval code make sure you are using $_GET and not $_POST.

Comment: Yes, I'm using $_GET for retrieving values, I tried both $_GET and $_POST and both work with the submit button. I've also tried to  prompt an alert and it just seems it's not seeing any javascript at all. It's driving me nuts..

Comment: for sake of trying, you can put there "javascript:this.form.submit();" instead.

Comment: Yay, tried that also. It looks like this might be a Wordpress issue with javascript, alerts aren't working either and that IS weird. I might try with jquery..